# Generate list of dataframes and apply function

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, lapply

I want to generate a list of dataframes and apply the same functions to each of them. I do not know how to do this elegantly without a very large number of lines of code.

From a dataframe df,

```
id <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e')
x <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 25, sd = 3)
y <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 4.5)
z <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 70000, sd = 10)
type <- c(rep("gold", 2),
            rep("silver", 4),
            rep("bronze", 4))
df <- data.frame(id, x, y, z, type)
```

I create a bunch of other datasets with a simple threshold rule based on one variable

```
df_25 <- df[df$x < 25,]
df_20 <- df[df$x < 20,] 
# and so on
```

I then apply functions to each dataset; I can do this to each dataset individually, or to a list of datasets

```
# individually
df <- df_18 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(nb1= sum(x),
                nb2 = sum(x != 25))

# to a list 
ls1 <- list(df_25, df_20)

func_1 <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(nb1= sum(x),
                nb2 = sum(x != 25))
}

ls1 <- lapply(ls1, function(x) {x[c("id","x")] 
  <- lapply(x[c("id","x")], func_1)
  x})


df_25 <- ls1[[1]]

df_20 <- ls1[[2]]
```

In any case this takes both a lot of lines and time as I am dealing with very large datasets. How could I simplify and fasten both the generation of datasets with proper recognisable names and the creation of the new variables through the functions defined above?

I did not find proper answer to this dual question yet and would welcome your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a `threshold` vector and `lapply` your aggregation. In base R this could look like this:

```
threshold <- c(22, 24, 26)

res <- setNames(lapply(threshold, function(s) {
  sst <- df[df$x < s, ]
  merge(sst, 
        with(sst, aggregate(list(nb1=x, nb2=x != 25), 
                            by=list(id=id), sum), by="id"))
}), threshold)

res
# $`22`
#   id        x        y        z   type      nb1 nb2
# 1  a 20.92786 37.61272 69976.23   gold 20.92786   1
# 2  b 20.64275 38.02056 69997.25 silver 20.64275   1
# 3  c 18.58916 46.08353 69985.98 silver 18.58916   1
# 
# $`24`
#   id        x        y        z   type      nb1 nb2
# 1  a 22.73948 44.29524 70002.81   gold 43.66734   2
# 2  a 20.92786 37.61272 69976.23   gold 43.66734   2
# 3  b 20.64275 38.02056 69997.25 silver 20.64275   1
# 4  c 18.58916 46.08353 69985.98 silver 18.58916   1
# 
# $`26`
#   id        x        y        z   type      nb1 nb2
# 1  a 22.73948 44.29524 70002.81   gold 43.66734   2
# 2  a 20.92786 37.61272 69976.23   gold 43.66734   2
# 3  b 20.64275 38.02056 69997.25 silver 20.64275   1
# 4  c 18.58916 46.08353 69985.98 silver 44.24036   2
# 5  c 25.65120 44.85778 70008.81 bronze 44.24036   2
# 6  d 24.84056 49.22505 69993.87 bronze 24.84056   1
```

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), 
    x = c(22.7394803492982, 20.927856140076, 30.2395154764033, 
    26.6955462205898, 20.6427460111819, 18.589158456851, 25.6511987559726, 
    24.8405634272769, 28.8534602413068, 26.5376546472448), y = c(44.2952365501829, 
    37.6127198429065, 45.2842176546081, 40.3835729432985, 38.0205610647157, 
    46.083525703352, 44.8577760657779, 49.2250487481642, 40.2699166395278, 
    49.3740993403725), z = c(70002.8091832317, 69976.2314543058, 
    70000.9974233725, 70011.435897774, 69997.249180665, 69985.9786882474, 
    70008.8088326676, 69993.8665395223, 69998.7334115052, 70001.2935411788
    ), type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("bronze", "gold", "silver"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `purrr::map` to loop over the vector of thresholds

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(c(18,20,25) %>%set_names() , ~ df %>% filter(x<.x) %>% 
                          group_by(id) %>%
                          mutate(nb1= sum(x),
                          nb2 = sum(x != 25)))
```

Or using `map_if` to apply the calculation for df subset with `nrow()>1`.

```
map_if(c(18,20,25) %>%set_names(), ~df %>% filter(x<.x) %>% nrow()>1,
                    ~df %>% filter(x<.x) %>% group_by(id) %>%
                            mutate(nb1= sum(x),
                            nb2 = sum(x != 25)), .else = ~NA)
```

Comment: great that's perfect! just two more things:

1. is that the fastest method if I have about 30 large datasets?
2. how do you loop for the list of datasets so as to avoid retrieving them all individually?

Comment: As Hadley said `purrr` was built using C++ so it should be fast, I think you may need to enhance this part `df %>% filter(x<.x) %>% nrow()>1` or maybe use something less expensive.For 2. and If I understand correctly you need `purrr::map2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` we can combine all this operations in one chain.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_split(x > 25, keep = FALSE) %>%
  map(. %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(nb1= sum(x),nb2 = sum(x != 25)))


#[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   id [5]
#  id        x     y      z type     nb1   nb2
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <int>
#1 a      21.4  42.9 70001. gold    21.4     1
#2 b      18.0  45.3 70005. silver  18.0     1
#3 c      23.3  42.7 70006. bronze  23.3     1
#4 d      23.4  40.9 69990. bronze  46.7     2
#5 d      23.3  41.2 70000. bronze  46.7     2
#6 e      22.3  55.9 69991. bronze  22.3     1

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   id [3]
#  id        x     y      z type     nb1   nb2
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <int>
#1 a      25.8  40.5 69995. gold    25.8     1
#2 b      28.3  41.5 69996. silver  54.5     2
#3 b      26.3  49.3 69993. silver  54.5     2
#4 c      26.5  44.5 69986. silver  26.5     1
```

Here, I have split the data into two groups based on value of `x`,first group is values below 25 and second group is above 25. You might change the logic based on your requirement.

This gives you list of dataframes as output which you can access individually.

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
id <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e')
x <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 25, sd = 3)
y <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 4.5)
z <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 70000, sd = 10)
type <- c(rep("gold", 2),rep("silver", 4),rep("bronze", 4))
df <- data.frame(id, x, y, z, type)
```

Comment: thanks! but how do you:
1. include as many conditions as needed in group_split so as to create more than 1 dataset from df?
2. I do not want to create a dataset that corresponds to the lines that do not meet the conditions, hence group_split may not be ideal?
3. avoid having to retrieve each dataset with ```df_25 <- ls2[[2]]``` (assuming you set ls2 <- df %>% group_split...)?

Comment: @unisateur2 You can remove the rows which do not match your criteria first from `df` by using `filter`, so start with `df %>% filter(....) %>% group_split(..)` ?

Comment: Hi, this does not answer the question posted by op. The groups are not disjoint, for example `x<25` is as superset of `x<20`.